# ChildComponent is still re-rendered despite using useCallBack

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have App.js that looks like this:

```js
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";
import { useState, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState("");
  const [anotherProp, setAnotherProp] = useState(1);

  const handleInputChange = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setPageTitle(e.target.value);
    },
    [pageTitle]
  );

  const handleIncrement = useCallback(() => {
    setAnotherProp(anotherProp + 1);
  }, [anotherProp]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChildComponent title={pageTitle} handleInputChange={handleInputChange} />

      <div>
        {anotherProp}
        <input
          type={"button"}
          value={"Increment Count"}
          onClick={handleIncrement}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The child component looks like this:

```
function ChildComponent({ title, handleInputChange }) {
  console.log("Child Component renders");
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleInputChange} />
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Since I have used `useCallBack` I expect that when I click on the button to increment count, my child component should remain unaffected and not re-render. But my child component still re-renders.

Can you help me understanding why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the standard behaviour of React. It will rerender its children when the parent component rerenders, even if the child's props didn't change. In this case, your parent is rerendering as its state is updating (the `anotherProp` counter).

If you want to prevent a particular component from rerendering when its props remain unchanged, you can use [`React.memo()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) by wrapping your `ChildComponent` in it, eg:

```js
export default memo(ChildComponent);
```

With this, React won't rerender your `ChildComponent` when its props remain unchanged.

On a side note, the `[pageTitle]` dependency for your first `useCallback()` hook is unnecessary, and can instead just be `[]` as your callback does not use this state value inside of it.

Comment: Oh Well. thank you. Using `memo` solved the problem. So both `useCallBack` as well as `memo` inside the child component is necessary for this to work. Just one wouldn't do the job. Is that corrrect?

Comment: @ABGR Yes, that's normally the case. Unless you're passing primitives into your child (and not objects such as functions), then there is no need to use hooks like `useMemo()`/`useCallback()` in the parent. Similarly, the `React.memo()` function can accept a second argument which tells React if the props are equal or not, so there may be scenarios where that's used to determine if particular objects are the same or not without needing to cache them with `useCallback()`/`useMemo()` in the parent. But in most cases, you'll use them in combination.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please also elaborate the sidenote part. I can see it works if I remove `pageTitle` from the dependency array and works with it as well. So Can you elaborate in which case should we be using and which case we can skip that? What I thought was since `pageTitle` was a prop to the child component. Whenever, that changes, we should be rendering the child component and hence this was in the dep list.

Comment: @ABGR The dependency array should include state/props that's used by the callback function. Since `pageTitle` isn't being used by the callback function, there isn't a need to include it in the array. As you mentioned, `pageTitle` is being passed as a prop to the `ChildComponent`, if any of the props change for a memoized component, then the `ChildComponent` will be rerendered, so even if `handleInputChange` remains stable between renders and doesn't change, the fact that `pageTitle` is chaining will cause the child component to rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of answer. Combination of useCallback and useMemo

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Child from './components/child.js';

function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const handleUpdateNum = useCallback((num) => {
    setNum(num + 1);
  }, []);

  const getChildComp = useMemo(
    () => <Child handleUpdateNum={handleUpdateNum} />,
    [handleUpdateNum]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{num}</h1>
      {getChildComp}
      <button onClick={() => handleUpdateNum(num)}> Addition </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child.js

```
import React from 'react';
function Child() {
  console.log('child component rendered');

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Child;
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the dependency array in the useCallback for handleInputChange. You have pageTitle as a dependency, which causes the handleInputChange function to be recreated whenever pageTitle changes.
So Remove pageTitle from the dependency array to prevent unnecessary recreations, and it should work as expected.

Comment: That's not the issue here. OP said _" I expect that when I click on the button to increment count, my child component should remain unaffected and not render"_, its `anotherProp` that's changing and still causing the rerender, not `pageTitle`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).